# How to run a java program without a console

Tags: java, command-line, headless

I need to run an java program even the terminal is closed....
in server....

Comment: In case you run out of dots, there you go: ............................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 7):

**On Unix and GNU/Linux systems you can run the program using `nohup` like this, assuming it is a jar:**

```
nohup java -jar program.jar &
```

To get the output of the program run into a text file so later on you can view it, you can do:

```
nohup java -jar program.jar > program.log &
```

There are packages that will wrap your Java programs into **services** too, which is more manageable than bare `java` processes.

You probably also want to use a **"process wrapper"** ([Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) maybe?) to give your process a meaningful name, otherwise all your Java programs will appear as `java` in the process list, which isn't very indicative.

Answer (score 2):

An "alternative" to `nohup` would be `screen`.  `screen` is very useful and allows you to run any task, detach the screen, and let it run in the background. You can resume it later.

> To run a task:
>
> ```
> screen <command_you_want_to_run>
> ```
>
> Then `<ctrl> <a> <d>` to detach from the
>   screen session.
>
> The next time you log in you can
>   reattach to the screen session with:
>
> ```
> screen -r
> ```
>
> If you have multiple screen sessions
>   running you will be presented with
>   their details and can connect to them
>   like this:
>
> ```
> screen -r 1234.pts-1.hostname
> ```
>
> ... where `1234.pts-1.hostname` is one
>   of the returned values from the output
>   from screen -r.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [javaw](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) command instead of `java`.

Comment: It will still get shut down when the user logs out.

Comment: @Michael, Well the question is not clear, I thought he mean that the console should not run while the app is running.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [headless mode](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/).  This will cause any calls that attempt to communicate with a screen, keyboard, mouse, etc to fail, but also means that you won't need an X server (on Unix) or access to the console (on Windows).

Comment: This is only relevant when you're using GUI-related classes, which most server applications never do.

Comment: It's very relevant for working with images on a server, since all of the image processing classes depend upon the AWT.  Using headless will give you a simpler version of the AWT that doesn't require a window.

Comment: It is also relevant if you use the lazy threading trick of putting background tasks on AWT thread in a program that may not even have a graphical interface.